# Python: Constraint to normalize weights, such that no weight is greater than 1/sqrt(n)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, constraints, normalization

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
df:

    a   b
 0  1   3
 1  2   4
```

I have a sample size N=5. I want to normalize the weights in the dataframe using

```
df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

and enforce a constraint, such that none of the weights are greater than 1/sqrt(N).

Can this be done in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To normalize and ensure that no value is greater than a reference, you need to get the max of the normalized values and normalize again:

```
import numpy as np
N = 5 # 1/np.sqrt(N) = 0.447214
df2 = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
df2 = df2.div(df2.values.max()*np.sqrt(N))
```

Output:

```
          a         b
0  0.149071  0.447214
1  0.198762  0.397523
```

This is two steps, two lines as the second step depends on the first one.

Can you do it in one line? Yes, but should you?

By performing the same computation twice: inefficient

```
N = 5
df2 = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).div(df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).values.max()*np.sqrt(N))
```

By using an assignment expression: not as readable

```
N = 5
df2 = (df2:=df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)).div(df2.values.max()*np.sqrt(N))
```

I would stick with the two lines

Comment: It is working on the dataframe I posted here. But for some reason, on the original dataframe I have (which is much larger) I get all entries NaN for some reason.

Comment: Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: Not without an example, can you provide one?

Comment: Alright I had the problem misunderstood. If any weight is greater than 1/sqrt(N), it should be clipped to 1/sqrt(N) and the remaining weight is distributed in a pro-rata fashion based on their relative weights. Could this be done? Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: You should provide an example in your question

Comment: I asked a more detailed question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70218241/python-set-constraint-to-normalized-weights